# Application works if installed from PC, but crashes if installed from store (WinPhone 7.5)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I have a project that runs on Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 7.5.

It works fine on 8 devices in all cases, but on Windows Phone 7.5 it crashes on startup with following message (only if installed from store):

[image]

If the application is built on PC and uploaded to device it works fine. I tried numerous things but nothing helped.

Comment: How did your app pass the certification?

Comment: I'have the same issue. Application pass the certification, but not work even on my device

Comment: Microsoft send me a email, thay explain that is was a Marketplace bug from 04 Dec to 12 Dec

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it was a store issue. Should be resolved now.

[Issue with 7.1 XAP submissions between Dec 04 and Dec 12 (Beta and Non-beta apps)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/ca3cc3cd-1c90-48d5-813d-f45209fc9ab3/issue-with-71-xap-submissions-between-dec-04-and-dec-12-beta-and-nonbeta-apps?forum=wpsubmit)

Comment: i really didn't expect that

Answer (score 0):

Well, my assumption is that your *XAP* file does not contains all the *DLLs* needed. Make sure the references to those *DLLs*  indicate `CopyLocal=True`. Also it would be nice if you can share the beta link to check your stack traces.

P.S. this may help:

[Troubleshooting Windows Phone App Problems that occur after Submitting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2859130)

[Your Windows Phone 7/8 application tests fine, but fails after publishing to Marketplace or after private app distribution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/05/08/your-published-windows-phone-7-8-application-fails-to-run.aspx)

Comment: How you can read above i said that app work on wp8 and if i upload app to device(wp7.5) from pc it works fine. CopyLocal for all libraries set true.

Comment: The above referenced article identifies several pitfalls that might apply only on WP7.5 platform.  Please check all the possibilities mentioned in the article and follow up here after you've confirmed that none of them applies.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a problem with the Async pack binding. You might want to try to remove the package and readd. More below:

[Async Targeting Pack troubleshooting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx)

In the past I was able to repro many post certification issues just by run the release version of the app from Visual Studio and simply unplug the cable while it is running. Sure you can't debug it but at least you can repro and test it without submitting it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your advice, but error has gone away. I don't do anything, i think that it was something with store...