# Strange windows phone app crashes only from the store

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to update a 7.1 app from the store.  For some reason it crashes only when installed from the store and only on 7.1 or 7.8 devices.  My Lumia 920 with the latest updates works fine.  The app runs fine if installed from VS 2010 or VS 2012.  Of course all emulators worked fine.  I put a Messagebox at Application_UnhandledException and it displayed this:

> The type 'MyApp.MainPage', specified in the x:Class of
>   '/MainPage.xaml' could not be found in any loaded assembly.

Of course the MainPage class is there.

The app uses GPS and bing map and has capabilities:

```
ID_CAP_LOCATION
ID_CAP_NETWORKING
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: You're going to need to provide some more detail. I can't honestly believe you think that anyone could answer this question based on this limited data. Please provide more.

Comment: Can you suggest what other information I need to provide?

Comment: You could post the app name for starters so I can go download it and try it on some different devices.

Comment: You could post the XAP file somewhere so I could decompile it and look for errors.

Comment: You could post sample code of where you think the error could be

Comment: You could post what you have tried up to this point.

Comment: You could post what research you have done on this issue.

Comment: App name is "WeekendTides" which I submitted more than 6 months ago.  Now I just made some simple changes on the drawings only and it failed.  The difference is of course I have downloaded all the latest SDK.  I first tried using VS2012 and then later tried using the same old VS2010.  All failed.  Not sure how I can post the XAP but here's the beta link that's failing on some older devices: http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=fd3a55db-ee10-42b5-a9f0-958925787a3f

Comment: Ill look more at it later but the app (not the beta) works on my Lumia 925. Ill test it on some other devices tonight.

Comment: Can you show the properties of MyApp.dll?

Comment: @d.lavysh, did you mean the public properties in the class or the file system properites of the dll?

Comment: file system properties

Comment: Have a look on answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466970/application-works-if-installed-from-pc-but-crashes-if-installed-from-store-win

Comment: @d.lavysh  not sure what you are looking for in the file system properites.  The DLL is there, It's got the version, Language = "Language Neutral".  Size 588KB.  Anything particular you are interested?

Comment: It seems it's a dev center bug.  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/f1e564c4-5217-4810-b0b5-40e6b6ad17ad/wp7-beta-app-exits-immediately?forum=wpsubmit&prof=required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a weird issue where my app worked differently from the store than on my device and the emulator. In my case it was because of trial mode. Apps run as though they are purchased when deployed to the emulator or device. It worked on my device from the store too, but that's because I bought it. Any other device which had not bought it ran in trial mode, and that's why it worked differently. I am betting that is why you are experiencing this crash. If it is not then we'll need more information.

Comment: It's not trial as mine is a Free app.  What other info you think you need?

Comment: Ok, my answer won't work for you then. For more info we'd like to see the full stack trace. Go to the dev center and download the stack trace for your app under the app crashes section and post what the stacktrace is.

Comment: I have been waiting for the crash report but so far none shown.  I did put a little tracing message here and there and I know it invoked a class to do the SQL CE DB load at App start and then attempted to load the MainPage (the 1st UI page) and that's when I think it couldn't find it.  I know the MainPage is there because the same beta link works on Lumia 920.  So it must be some 7.1 devices having problem with that MainPage class which I did not even change  for this update.

Answer (score 1):

I have just solved a similar problem where I had this error message when running from Visual Studio on my phone but not in an emulator. My problem was that I had different versions of the Microsoft.Live Assemblies in my 'main' app and the Assembly which contained the 'MainPage.xaml'.